# SQLITE: Index BLOB data, vs multi-part indexes on high cardinality data

Tags: sqlite

So I am looking for potential feedback on the issues and benefits around storing many 100's of millions of rows of memory address data.

The addresses consist of 8 x UInt32 positions, I was initially going to store the data in 8 columns, and have an 8 way multipart index on those columns.

```
CREATE TABLE address (position1 INTEGER, position2 INTEGER, positionN ......)
```

But it then dawned on me that I could also have a BLOB column, and just store 64 bytes of data and index that.

```
CREATE TABLE address (position BLOB)
```

So I guess it becomes a question about any known efficiencies or detrimental effects of looking up on an 8 way index vs a far larger binary index, both with high cardinality.

There will be duplicate, timestamped, entries for the same positions although they will be fairly infrequent.

The table will be read and added to constantly if that helps, with a 3(read)/1(write) ratio.

Many thanks.

Comment: Indices comes at a cost when adding rows, their benefit is when searching. You have to answer yourself (and us) - what are you going to use this database for? What will you be searching for? And, seeing this is some kind of log, will a simple text file suffice?

Comment: @MrGumble My appologies I thought it was fairly clear, I need to store a combination of 8 x UInt32 values.  So bigger than an UInt64, these in combination describe a unique path within a block of memory to construct a far larger address within a memory structure.  I will need to query to see if this path has been checked already, and if not write an entry marking that path.  A log it is not, and a file would be of little use for lookups.   There may be duplicate entries for the exact path combination.  So it's really knowing if multipart indexes have an efficiency for the sub-indexed segments.

Comment: This depends on the details of [SQLite's record format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format). Would most of the actual values fit into 16 bits?

Comment: @CL. Sadly,  most of them would be in the 32 bit area,  were you thinking of encoding the values into 2x64 bit integers?

Comment: With the additional 7 type bytes, only 16-bit values would save space (and thus I/O time), on average. If you're going to encode anyway, just use a blob.